# Stanford-NLP identify action verbs in a sentence

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am using standford NLP demo site(http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process) to process a sentence. In my case, I just needs to identify action verb/s in a sentence.

Is there a way to identify action verbs from the stanford NLP output(JSON or XML)? The sentence I am trying as an example is "when a teacher assigns a project, student tries to make it.". So in this sentence, I just need the verbs "assigns" and "makes" and not the verb "tries". Here is the parse tree with POS tags for the sentence:

(ROOT\n  (S\n    (SBAR\n      (WHADVP (WRB when))\n      (S\n        (NP (DT a) (NN teacher))\n        (VP (VBZ assigns)\n          (NP (DT a) (NN project)))))\n    (, ,)\n    (NP (NN student))\n    (VP (VBZ tries)\n      (S\n        (VP (TO to)\n          (VP (VB make)\n            (NP (PRP it))))))\n    (. .)))

Comment: Did you got any help on this?

Comment: nope, no help yet.